# Linq - Join with group by merging results

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by

I'm trying to merge the results from two tables in to a list and then display it in a dictionary where the key is the domain and the value is a list of urls from both tables.

```
class Source1Entity { string Domain {get;} string PageUrl {get;} /* more properties */ }
class Source2Entity { string Domain {get;} string PageUrl {get;} /* more properties */ }
```

I've got this far:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> results = 
     from firstSource in context.Source1
     join secondSource in context.Source2 on firstSource.Domain equals secondSource.Domain
     group firstSource by firstSource.Domain into g
     ...
```

Comment: If a domain only appears in a single table, do you want it anyway? It's not clear that you really want to *join* these tables so much as concatenate them...

Comment: You need a group join

Comment: Can you edit  your post & add desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear, but I *suspect* you actually want to treat these two tables as equivalents - so you can project to a common form and then use `Concat`, then call `ToLookup`:

```
var projectedSource1 = context.Source1.Select(x => new { x.Domain, x.PageUrl });
var projectedSource2 = context.Source2.Select(x => new { x.Domain, x.PageUrl });
var results = projectedSource1
    .Concat(projectedSource2)
    .ToLookup(x => x.Domain, x => x.PageUrl);
```

Then:

```
// For a particular domain - you'll get an empty sequence it the
// domain isn't represented
foreach (var url in results[domain])
```

or

```
foreach (var entry in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}", entry.Key);
    foreach (var url in entry)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Url: {0}", url);
    }
}
```

While you *could* use a `Dictionary` for this, a `Lookup` is generally more suitable for single-key-multiple-value queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need a GroupJoin.
Try this...

```
join  secondSource in context.Source on firstSource.Domain equals secondSource.Domain into group_join
```